# Tools to migrate index from elasticsearch 1.x to elasticsearch 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0

I am looking for the tools to migrate data from 1.x to 2.x elasticsearch. Please suggest if anything is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. You can use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html) in order to copy indices from your old 1.x ES to your new 2.x ES:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["old-es:9200"]                     <--- source ES host
   index => "source_index"                      <--- source index to copy
   docinfo => true
  }
}
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp" ]  <--- remove added junk
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["new-es:9200]"                     <--- target ES host
   index => "%{[@metadata][_index]}"
   document_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"
   document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
 }
}
```

You can also use [elasticdump](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump) and use the following commands to copy `source_index` from `old-es:9200` to your `new-es:9200` host:

```
elasticdump \
  --input=http://old-es:9200/source_index \
  --output=http://new-es:9200/source_index \
  --type=analyzer
elasticdump \
  --input=http://old-es:9200/source_index \
  --output=http://new-es:9200/source_index \
  --type=mapping
elasticdump \
  --input=http://old-es:9200/source_index \
  --output=http://new-es:9200/source_index \
  --type=data
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @val .. you are amazing.. :) I did used elasticdump as my both the servers are in different network and there is no route, so i cannot use logstash. With elasticdumnp i took the dump in file and then transferred the file to the new instance and put the dump in the new server. It worked perfect.. Thanks again