# Find and replace in elasticsearch all documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elastic-stack

I wanted to replace the single username in all my elasticsearch index documents. Is there any API query ?

I tried searching multiple but couldn't find. Any one has idea?

My scenario:

```html
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/movies/' -d '{"user":"mad", "role":"tester"}'
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/movies/' -d '{"user":"bob", "role":"engineer"}'
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/movies/' -d '{"user":"cat", "role":"engineer"}'
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/movies/' -d '{"user":"bob", "role":"doctor"}'
```

I have the above data in the index called "test" and type "movies". Here I wanted to replace all the "bob" name with "alice".

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Index the data provided? Search? There are different URLs/HTTP method combinations for each. `-XPUT` for a particular type/index will index a document (replacing it if you specify an existing ID) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-doc.html  `-XGET` with particular type/index to get a specific record https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/get-doc.html  etc.

Comment: I know how to do update using for one document by taking index ID. But the index id is generated automatically. I wanted to replace one string with another in all the documents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[update-by-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) is the way to go.

```json
POST /test/movies/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.user = 'alice'"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user": "bob"
    }
  }
}
```

Note: make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this to work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like charm.

Comment: Do we need to enable groovy and inline script for this?

If you know exact syntax could you please comment here?

 script.inline: true
 script.indexed: true

Comment: Good point, yes, you do, I will update my answer to mention it.

Comment: For 2.3.4 still not working, after enabling in elasticsearch.yml and after restart the service.

Here is the error I am getting


{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"script_exception","reason":"failed to run inline script [ctx._source.user = alice] using lang [groovy]"}],"type":"script_exception","reason":"failed to run inline script [ctx._source.user = alice] using lang [groovy]","caused_by":{"type":"missing_property_exception","reason":"No such property: alice for class: 11d6dc9400ad10c4b07xxxxxxxxxxxxx}},"status":500}

Comment: You need single quotes (or escaped double quotes) around alice, i.e. `ctx._source.user = 'alice'`

Comment: Fixed it. Working. Do you know any way to export data into json ?

Comment: Good. Yes, elasticdump is a good candidate tool for that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517663/tools-to-migrate-index-from-elasticsearch-1-x-to-elasticsearch-2-x/38517865#38517865