# How can I set default field value when updating ES mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-api

I have "stores" index in elasticsearch and want to add "chain" field with following json:

```
{
"properties": {
    "chain": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": true
    }
}
```

How can I set default value for all existiong documents in the index?

Comment: If there is no way to do that, how do I update all the documents without retrieving all the ids and bulk updating them?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636348/find-and-replace-in-elasticsearch-all-documents/38636633#38636633 (hint: use update-by-query)

Comment: Yes, this will help.
Thanks!